# How to tell compromised network users that their network is compromised

Tags: router

If I were to use Shodan and discover that someone is using an "admin/admin" creds for their router admin page. How can I tell them that? Is there a way to redirect their DNS queries to a page that says: please change your router password?

Comment: That would most probably a criminal act in most jurisdictions.

Comment: How would you feel if you came home one day and found a note on your bed that said, "I found your front door wasn't very secure, so I decided to leave you this note.  I hope you change your locks."?

Comment: On the flip side: Howdy-ho, neighbor! I saw a bunch of criminals in your house yesterday. They were trafficking stolen goods and kiddie porn while using the house as a base of operations for breaking into other houses. I did nothing, and you are responsible for their activities. Have a nice day! (BTW, not saying it *is* legal, but there are legal arguments us here in SF won't know about and will vary, greatly, by jurisdiction.)

Answer (score 4):

Even logging in to the router which you're not supposed to access would be a problem legally. Changing anything even more so. Reporting this to their ISP (based on a whois query) is pretty much the only "by the book" way to proceed.